# Visual Studio 2015 Application properties window null reference error

Tags: uiwebview, visual-studio-2015, windows-10-universal, windows-10-desktop

I am creating a project in VS2015. template i have choose is blank Universal app.

An error occurred trying to load the page.

> Property accessor 'TargetDescriptions' on object
>   'Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectFlavoring.Automation.Project.CommonProjectExtender'
>   threw the following exception:'Value cannot be null. Parameter name:
>   targets'.

[image: Error message]

Answer (score 0):

I get issues accessing some projects properties due to addins I've added to my VS (GhostDoc): can you try to disable all your addins to check of that work ?

Comment: Problem started when i update from   Build 10240  to Build 10586. Prior to that, It is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I reinsatlled the nuget package manger: https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/5d345edc-2e2d-4a9c-b73b-d53956dc458d

I restart the visual studio

and it works fine for me.